Por que se sobre escriben mis registros en la BD java srping boot
estoy desarrollando un método de inserción masiva de registros en las cuales consiste en recibir un ArrayList de objetos e iterar por cada registro para ir ingresando la información en la bd, pero si yo le mando más de un registro, el segundo registro se pierde, e intente hacer de 1 por uno, pero me sigue sobre escribiendo los registros
public String InsertarInmuebles(List<Inmuebles> list, Integer Id_tercero){
        try{
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                if(repositorioTerceros.findById(Id_tercero).isPresent()){
                    Inmuebles inmuebles = list.get(i);
                    // Imprimir cada inmueble individual
                    Terceros terceros = repositorioTerceros.findByIDTercero(Id_tercero);
                    inmuebles.setTerceros(terceros);
                    repositorioInmubles.save(inmuebles);
                }
            }
            return "Inmuebles registrados con exito";
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Ha ocurrido un error: " + e.getMessage();
        }
 }             


¿Estás guardando en base de datos verdad (repositorioInmubles.save(inmuebles);) ?

En este caso podrías usar @Transactional, veo que estás iterando sobre la lista  inmuebles y además guardando información

@Transactional: esta anotación, se utiliza para marcar un método o una
clase como transaccional, lo que significa que cualquier operación de
base de datos realizada dentro del método o clase marcado se ejecutará
dentro de una transacción. Si la transacción tiene éxito, los cambios
se confirmarán en la base de datos. Si se produce un error y la
transacción se revierte, los cambios no persistirán en la base de
datos.

por cierto, la iteración sobre la lista de objetos inmueble (             for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){ ) no es necesaria, ya que obtienes primeramente el valor de terceros y posteriormente itera sobre la lista de objetos Inmuebles
@Transactional
public String InsertarInmuebles(List<Inmuebles> list, Integer Id_tercero){
    try{
        if(repositorioTerceros.findById(Id_tercero).isPresent()){
            Terceros terceros = repositorioTerceros.findByIDTercero(Id_tercero); //*Obtiene valor terceros con base al Id 
            for (Inmuebles inmuebles : list) { //*Itera sobre lista
                inmuebles.setTerceros(terceros);
                repositorioInmubles.save(inmuebles); //*Guarda
            }
            return "Inmuebles registrados con exito";
        } else {
            return "No se encontró en repositorioTerceros el id: " + Id_tercero;
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Ha ocurrido un error: " + e.getMessage();
    }
}


Si me funciono, muchas gracias

Excelente @OmarDiaz , recuerda marcar la respuesta como solucion, revisa [tour]
